# multiprocessing: How do I share a dict among multiple processes?

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing, shared-variable

A program that creates several processes that work on a join-able queue, `Q`, and may eventually manipulate a global dictionary `D` to store results. (so each child process may use `D` to store its result and also see what results the other child processes are producing)

If I print the dictionary D in a child process, I see the modifications that have been done on it (i.e. on D). But after the main process joins Q, if I print D, it's an empty dict!

I understand it is a synchronization/lock issue. Can someone tell me what is happening here, and how I can synchronize access to D?

Comment: This does not work as expected at least on python 3.7.2 using osx 10.14.4 Dict is not synchronized and its contents are rewritten by other processes.
However, <code>multiprocessing.Manager().list()</code> works as expected.

Comment: If you decide to use a manager to accomplish this, then know that it will not work for nested dictionaries. However, here is an approach that you can use to make it work with and share nested dictionaries and lists https://stackoverflow.com/a/73418403/16310741

Answer (score 247):

A general answer involves using a [`Manager`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) object. Adapted from the docs:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def f(d):
    d[1] += '1'
    d['2'] += 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()

    d = manager.dict()
    d[1] = '1'
    d['2'] = 2

    p1 = Process(target=f, args=(d,))
    p2 = Process(target=f, args=(d,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    print d
```

Output:

```
$ python mul.py 
{1: '111', '2': 6}
```

Comment: Thanks senderle. Indeed, D = multiprocessing.Manager().dict() solves my problem.

I was using D = dict().

Comment: @LorenzoBelli, if you're asking whether access to the manager is synchronized, I believe the answer is yes. `multiprocessing.Manager()` returns an [instance of `SyncManager`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.sharedctypes.multiprocessing.Manager), the name of which suggests as much!

Comment: @senderle I want to share numpy random state of a parent process with a child process. I've tried using `Manager` but still no luck. Could you please take a look at my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49372619/how-to-share-numpy-random-state-of-a-parent-process-with-child-processes) and see if you can offer a solution? I can still get different random numbers if I do `np.random.seed(None)` every time that I generate a random number, but this does not allow me to use the random state of the parent process, which is not what I want. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you generalize if there is a way to get an already existing dict managed?

Comment: @RadioControlled happy to write an update, but briefly, while I don't think you can make this happen directly, you can easily create a new managed dict with the same keys and values, and use that instead of the original. Is that adequate for your case?

Comment: @senderle, that's what I ended up doing. So the answer would be that you'd have to do just that.

Comment: How would this work if the Process object was being created dynamically in some other method? The dictionary won't be accessible inside that method. Could someone provide a hint ?

Comment: What if the value holding by some `dict` key is not a `pickle` serializable object? More specifically how to solve this problem?: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69430747/6907424

Comment: This answer is misleading. The dictionary DOES NOT allow for concurrent use. It's just a coincidence that this example works. Try putting `for i in range(1000)` in the `f()` function and you will see that it returns a different number every time.

Answer (score 42):

In addition to @senderle's here, some might also be wondering how to use the functionality of `multiprocessing.Pool`.

The nice thing is that there is a `.Pool()` method to the `manager` instance that mimics all the familiar API of the top-level `multiprocessing`.

```
from itertools import repeat
import multiprocessing as mp
import os
import pprint

def f(d: dict) -> None:
    pid = os.getpid()
    d[pid] = f"Hi, I was written by process {pid:d}"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with mp.Manager() as manager:
        d = manager.dict()
        with manager.Pool() as pool:
            pool.map(f, repeat(d, 10))
        # `d` is a DictProxy object that can be converted to dict
        pprint.pprint(dict(d))
```

Output:

```
$ python3 mul.py 
{22562: 'Hi, I was written by process 22562',
 22563: 'Hi, I was written by process 22563',
 22564: 'Hi, I was written by process 22564',
 22565: 'Hi, I was written by process 22565',
 22566: 'Hi, I was written by process 22566',
 22567: 'Hi, I was written by process 22567',
 22568: 'Hi, I was written by process 22568',
 22569: 'Hi, I was written by process 22569',
 22570: 'Hi, I was written by process 22570',
 22571: 'Hi, I was written by process 22571'}
```

This is a slightly different example where each process just logs its process ID to the global `DictProxy` object `d`.

Answer (score 41):

multiprocessing is not like threading.  Each child process will get a copy of the main process's memory.  Generally state is shared via communication (pipes/sockets), signals, or shared memory.

Multiprocessing makes some abstractions available for your use case - shared state that's treated as local by use of proxies or shared memory: http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

Relevant sections:

- http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#shared-ctypes-objects
- http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.managers

Comment: Thanks alot. You led me to the/a solution:  multiprocessing.Manager().dict().

Comment: Can someone elaborate on what the statement "Each child process will get a copy of the main process's memory" means.

Comment: @Itsme2003 by default a spawned process has no access to the memory of the parent process (this is one of thekey  differences to threads). So when a process needs an object of the parent process, it has to create a copy of it (instead of getting a reference to the actual object). The answer above elaborates on how to share objects between processes.

Comment: Because this is often mistaken: As long as you do not modify the object, at least in the usual Linux setup, the object will only actually be stored once in the memory. It will be copied as soon as it is changed. This can be very important if you need to save memory and do not modify the object.

Answer (score 25):

I'd like to share my own work that is faster than Manager's dict and is simpler and more stable than pyshmht library that uses tons of memory and doesn't work for Mac OS. Though my dict only works for plain strings and is immutable currently.
I use linear probing implementation and store keys and values pairs in a separate memory block after the table.

```
from mmap import mmap
import struct
from timeit import default_timer
from multiprocessing import Manager
from pyshmht import HashTable


class shared_immutable_dict:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.hs = 1 << (len(a) * 3).bit_length()
        kvp = self.hs * 4
        ht = [0xffffffff] * self.hs
        kvl = []
        for k, v in a.iteritems():
            h = self.hash(k)
            while ht[h] != 0xffffffff:
                h = (h + 1) & (self.hs - 1)
            ht[h] = kvp
            kvp += self.kvlen(k) + self.kvlen(v)
            kvl.append(k)
            kvl.append(v)

        self.m = mmap(-1, kvp)
        for p in ht:
            self.m.write(uint_format.pack(p))
        for x in kvl:
            if len(x) <= 0x7f:
                self.m.write_byte(chr(len(x)))
            else:
                self.m.write(uint_format.pack(0x80000000 + len(x)))
            self.m.write(x)

    def hash(self, k):
        h = hash(k)
        h = (h + (h >> 3) + (h >> 13) + (h >> 23)) * 1749375391 & (self.hs - 1)
        return h

    def get(self, k, d=None):
        h = self.hash(k)
        while True:
            x = uint_format.unpack(self.m[h * 4:h * 4 + 4])[0]
            if x == 0xffffffff:
                return d
            self.m.seek(x)
            if k == self.read_kv():
                return self.read_kv()
            h = (h + 1) & (self.hs - 1)

    def read_kv(self):
        sz = ord(self.m.read_byte())
        if sz & 0x80:
            sz = uint_format.unpack(chr(sz) + self.m.read(3))[0] - 0x80000000
        return self.m.read(sz)

    def kvlen(self, k):
        return len(k) + (1 if len(k) <= 0x7f else 4)

    def __contains__(self, k):
        return self.get(k, None) is not None

    def close(self):
        self.m.close()

uint_format = struct.Struct('>I')


def uget(a, k, d=None):
    return to_unicode(a.get(to_str(k), d))


def uin(a, k):
    return to_str(k) in a


def to_unicode(s):
    return s.decode('utf-8') if isinstance(s, str) else s


def to_str(s):
    return s.encode('utf-8') if isinstance(s, unicode) else s


def mmap_test():
    n = 1000000
    d = shared_immutable_dict({str(i * 2): '1' for i in xrange(n)})
    start_time = default_timer()
    for i in xrange(n):
        if bool(d.get(str(i))) != (i % 2 == 0):
            raise Exception(i)
    print 'mmap speed: %d gets per sec' % (n / (default_timer() - start_time))


def manager_test():
    n = 100000
    d = Manager().dict({str(i * 2): '1' for i in xrange(n)})
    start_time = default_timer()
    for i in xrange(n):
        if bool(d.get(str(i))) != (i % 2 == 0):
            raise Exception(i)
    print 'manager speed: %d gets per sec' % (n / (default_timer() - start_time))


def shm_test():
    n = 1000000
    d = HashTable('tmp', n)
    d.update({str(i * 2): '1' for i in xrange(n)})
    start_time = default_timer()
    for i in xrange(n):
        if bool(d.get(str(i))) != (i % 2 == 0):
            raise Exception(i)
    print 'shm speed: %d gets per sec' % (n / (default_timer() - start_time))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mmap_test()
    manager_test()
    shm_test()
```

On my laptop performance results are:

```
mmap speed: 247288 gets per sec
manager speed: 33792 gets per sec
shm speed: 691332 gets per sec
```

simple usage example:

```
ht = shared_immutable_dict({'a': '1', 'b': '2'})
print ht.get('a')
```

Comment: Github? Documentation? how can we use this tool?

Comment: I now get  with `from pyshmht import HashTable` that it cannot find HashTable module

Comment: Seems interesting, could you make it Python 3 compatible pls?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try **[pyshmht](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyshmht)**, sharing memory based hash table extension for Python.

**Notice**

1. It's not fully tested, just for your reference.
2. It currently lacks lock/sem mechanisms for multiprocessing.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I am not getting consistent outputs, e.g. the value of the `__total_count__` isn't always 20.

```
from itertools import repeat
import multiprocessing as mp
import os
import pprint
from functools import partial
import numpy as np
import time

def counter(value, d: dict) -> None:
    if value not in d:
        d["__unique_count__"] += 1
        d[value] = 1
    else:
        d[value] += 1

    d["__total_count__"] += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.freeze_support()
    with mp.Manager() as manager:
        d = manager.dict()
        d["__unique_count__"] = 0 
        d["__total_count__"] = 0
        numbers = np.random.randint(0,5,size=100)
        print(len(numbers))
        with manager.Pool() as pool:
            pool.map(partial(counter, d=d), numbers)
        # `d` is a DictProxy object that can be converted to dict
        final_d = dict(d)
        pprint.pprint(final_d)
        print(final_d["__unique_count__"], final_d["__total_count__"])
```

output1

```
100
{0: 26,
 1: 16,
 2: 26,
 3: 14,
 4: 18,
 '__total_count__': 92,
 '__unique_count__': 5}
5 92
```

output2

```
100
{0: 10,
 1: 21,
 2: 28,
 3: 22,
 4: 19,
 '__total_count__': 95,
 '__unique_count__': 5}
5 95
```