# Python multiprocessing manager class object thread/process safe

Tags: python, thread-safety, multiprocessing

I have the following class that is shared between multiple consumers (using producer/consumer methodology).  My question involves the methods called on this class.  Do I need to implement locks or is the manager class thread safe?

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing.manager import BaseManager

class SampleClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._count = 0

    # Does locking need to be implemented here?
    def increment(self):
        self._count += 1

BaseManager.register('SampleClass', SampleClass)
manager = BaseManager()
manager.start()

instance = manager.SampleClass()

jobs = []
for i in range(0, 5):
    p = mp.Process(target=some_func, args=(instance,))
    jobs.append(p)
    p.start()

for p in jobs:
    p.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think so. As said as a comment on this other question:

1. [multiprocessing: How do I share a dict among multiple processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832554/multiprocessing-how-do-i-share-a-dict-among-multiple-processes)

> Is `manager.dict()` this process safe?
>
> @LorenzoBelli, if you're asking whether access to the manager is synchronized, I believe the answer is yes. `multiprocessing.Manager()` returns an [instance of `SyncManager`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.sharedctypes.multiprocessing.Manager), the name of which suggests as much!