# Python Multiprocessing Scheduling

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, queue, scheduled-tasks

In Python 3.6, I am running multiple processes in parallel, where each process pings a URL and returns a Pandas dataframe. I want to keep running the (2+) processes continually, I have created a minimal representative example as below.

My questions are:

**1)** My understanding is that since I have different functions, I cannot use `Pool.map_async()` and its variants. Is that right? The only examples of these I have seen  were repeating the same function, like on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832554/multiprocessing-how-do-i-share-a-dict-among-multiple-processes).

**2)** What is the best practice to make this setup to run perpetually? In my code below, I use a `while` loop, which I suspect is not suited for this purpose.

**3)** Is the way I am using the `Process` and `Manager` optimal? I use `multiprocessing.Manager.dict()` as the shared dictionary to return the results form the processes. I saw in a comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415028/how-can-i-recover-the-return-value-of-a-function-passed-to-multiprocessing-proce) that using a `Queue` here would make sense, however the `Queue` object has no `.dict()' method. So, I am not sure how that would work.

I would be grateful for any improvements and suggestions **with example code**.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing
import time

def worker1(name, t , seed, return_dict):
    '''worker function'''
    print(str(name) + 'is here.')
    time.sleep(t)
    np.random.seed(seed)
    df= pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,8).reshape(2,4), columns=list('ABCD'))
    return_dict[name] = [df.columns.tolist()] + df.values.tolist()

def worker2(name, t, seed, return_dict):
    '''worker function'''
    print(str(name) + 'is here.')
    np.random.seed(seed)
    time.sleep(t)
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 1000, 12).reshape(3, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

    return_dict[name] = [df.columns.tolist()] + df.values.tolist()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t=1
    while True:

        start_time = time.time()
        manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
        parallel_dict = manager.dict()
        seed=np.random.randint(0,1000,1) # send seed to worker to return a diff df
        jobs = []
        p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker1, args=('name1', t, seed, parallel_dict))
        p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker2, args=('name2', t, seed+1, parallel_dict))
        jobs.append(p1)
        jobs.append(p2)
        p1.start()
        p2.start()
        for proc in jobs:
            proc.join()
        parallel_end_time = time.time() - start_time
        #print(parallel_dict)
        df1= pd.DataFrame(parallel_dict['name1'][1:],columns=parallel_dict['name1'][0])
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(parallel_dict['name2'][1:], columns=parallel_dict['name2'][0])
        merged_df = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=0)
        print(merged_df)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Answer 1 (map on multiple functions)

You're technically right.
With map, map_async and other variations, you should use a single function.

But this constraint can be bypassed by implementing an executor, and passing the function to execute as part of the parameters:

```py
def dispatcher(args):
    return args[0](*args[1:])
```

So a minimum working example:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

def function_1(v):
    print("hi %s"%v)
    return 1
    
def function_2(v):
    print("by %s"%v)
    return 2

def dispatcher(args):
    return args[0](*args[1:])

with mp.Pool(2) as p:
    tasks = [
        (function_1, "A"),
        (function_2, "B")
    ]
    r = p.map_async(dispatcher, tasks)
    r.wait()
    results = r.get()
```

### Answer 2 (Scheduling)

I would remove the while from the script and schedule a cron job ([on GNU/Linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cron.8.html)) ([on windows](https://active-directory-wp.com/docs/Usage/How_to_add_a_cron_job_on_Windows.html)) so that the OS will be responsible for it's execution.

On Linux you can run `cronotab -e` and add the following line to make the script run every 5 minutes.

```sh
*/5 * * * * python /path/to/script.py
```

### Answer 3 (Shared Dictionary)

yes but no.

To my knowledge using the Manager for data such as collections is the best way.
For Arrays or primitive types (int, floats, ecc) exists  `Value` and `Array`  [which are faster](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes).

As in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes)

> A manager object returned by Manager() controls a server process which holds > Python objects and allows other processes to manipulate them using proxies.
>
> A manager returned by Manager() will support types list, dict, Namespace, Lock, > RLock, Semaphore, BoundedSemaphore, Condition, Event, Barrier, Queue, Value and > Array.
>
> Server process managers are more flexible than using shared memory objects because they can be made to support arbitrary object types. Also, a single manager can be shared by processes on different computers over a network. They are, however, slower than using shared memory.

**But you have only to return a Dataframe, so the shared dictionary it's not needed.**

### Cleaned Code

Using all the previous ideas the code can be rewritten as:

**map version**

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep
import multiprocessing as mp

def worker1(t , seed):
    print('worker1 is here.')
    sleep(t)
    np.random.seed(seed)
    return pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,8).reshape(2,4), columns=list('ABCD'))
     

def worker2(t , seed):
    print('worker2 is here.')
    sleep(t)
    np.random.seed(seed)
    return pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 1000, 12).reshape(3, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

def dispatcher(args):
    return args[0](*args[1:])

def task_generator(sleep_time=1):
    seed = np.random.randint(0,1000,1)
    yield worker1, sleep_time, seed    
    yield worker2, sleep_time, seed + 1

with mp.Pool(2) as p:
    results = p.map(dispatcher, task_generator())
    merged = pd.concat(results, axis=0)
    print(merged)
```

If the process of concatenation of the Dataframe is the bottleneck, An approach with imap might become optimal.

**imap version**

```py
with mp.Pool(2) as p:
    merged = pd.DataFrame()
    for result in p.imap_unordered(dispatcher, task_generator()):
        merged = pd.concat([merged,result], axis=0)
    print(merged)
```

The main difference is that in the map case, the program first wait for all the process tasks to end, and then concatenate all the Dataframes.

While in the imap_unoredered case, As soon as a task as ended, the Dataframe is concatenated ot the current results.

Comment: Thank you very much. Would I not have to use `map_async()` instead of `map` in order for worker1` and `worker2` to run in parallel? Is there a reason you are using `map()`?

Comment: No problem! map distribute the tasks to all the processes on the Pool. So it is parallel! The difference is that map is blocking while map_async is non blocking. So with map you have to wait that all the task finished, while with map_async you will get some results objects and then you'll have to call result.wait() and result.get().