# How to efficiently build a list of dicts without duplicates?

Tags: python

In the code below, the 3rd and 4th elements are considered the same, because 'start' and 'end' are just switched:

```
{'start': '222',  'end': '333', 'type':'c'},
{'start': '333',  'end': '222', 'type':'c'}
```

I need to build a relations list or set which don't contain duplicates like above. Supposed the input is from list_of_dicts, and my code is the following to achieve the purpose:

```
relations = []
list_of_dicts = [{'start': '123',  'end': '456', 'type':'a'},
                  {'start': '111',  'end': '122', 'type':'b'},
                  {'start': '222',  'end': '333', 'type':'c'},
                  {'start': '333',  'end': '222', 'type':'c'},
                  ]

duplicate_keys = set()
for my_dict in list_of_dicts:
    duplicate_key = ''.join(sorted(my_dict['start'] + my_dict['end'] + my_dict['type']))
    if duplicate_key not in duplicate_keys:
        relations.append(my_dict)
        duplicate_keys.add(duplicate_key)

print(relations)
```

This seems to work. My list_of_dicts are supposed to be large, for example, 100 millions. Is this the fast way to do it? Also, the list_of_dicts here are illustrative purpose for convenience, but the 'relations' list are built from similar input.

Comment: If you want to be able to add them to sets, or use them as dict keys, see [`frozendict`](https://pypi.org/project/frozendict/).

Comment: No need to sort.  Just loop through and add both permutations as dict keys.

Comment: @user2263572, ...eh? No. They're _the same_. The ordering is not part of the dict itself. `{'a': 1, 'b': 2} == {'b': 2, 'a': 1}` is True. There's no reason whatsoever to add them as two separate items; and adding permutations is going to greatly increase memory usage.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy He wants to treat `start: 1, end: 2` as equivalent to `start: 2, end: 1`. It has nothing to do with dictionary ordering.

Comment: _Ahhh_. In that case we can just sort the values and ignore the keys (for which ordering is independent). Make both `start: 1, end:2` and `start: 2, end: 1` evaluate to `lower: 1, higher: 2` and you're done.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy But only start and end are considered, not type.

Comment: @Barmar, ...right, hence the "for which ordering is independent" caveat.

Comment: Also, the list_of_dicts don't exist. Each dict in 'list_of_dicts' are produced in a loop and add to the relations list/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is better to transform those dict into a specialize class, add to that class a hash function and let a `set` or a `dict` or similar take care of duplicates

```
>>> class MyObject:
        def __init__(self,start,end,type):
            self.data = (*sorted((start,end)),type)
        def __hash__(self):
            return hash(self.data)
        def __repr__(self):
            return f"{self.__class__.__name__}{self.data}"
        def __eq__(self,other):
            if isinstance(other,self.__class__):
                return self.data == other.data
            return False

    
>>> list_of_dicts = [{'start': '123',  'end': '456', 'type':'a'},
                  {'start': '111',  'end': '122', 'type':'b'},
                  {'start': '222',  'end': '333', 'type':'c'},
                  {'start': '333',  'end': '222', 'type':'c'},
                  ]
>>> new=[MyObject(**x) for x in list_of_dicts]
>>> new
[MyObject('123', '456', 'a'), MyObject('111', '122', 'b'), MyObject('222', '333', 'c'), MyObject('222', '333', 'c')]
>>> set(new)
{MyObject('123', '456', 'a'), MyObject('222', '333', 'c'), MyObject('111', '122', 'b')}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use dict and tuples for keys:

```py
list_of_dicts = [{'start': '123',  'end': '456', 'type':'a'},
                  {'start': '111',  'end': '122', 'type':'b'},
                  {'start': '222',  'end': '333', 'type':'c'},
                  {'start': '333',  'end': '222', 'type':'c'},
                  ]

for my_dict in list_of_dicts:
    k = tuple(sorted(my_dict.values()))

    if k not in relations:
        relations[k] = my_dict


print(list(relations.values()))
```

And one-liner with a little-bit different behavior:

```py
list_of_dicts = [{'start': '123',  'end': '456', 'type':'a'},
                  {'start': '111',  'end': '122', 'type':'b'},
                  {'start': '222',  'end': '333', 'type':'c'},
                  {'start': '333',  'end': '222', 'type':'c'},
                  ]

relations = list({tuple(sorted(my_dict.values())): my_dict for my_dict in list_of_dicts}.values())

print(relations)
```

In this one-liner, latest value will be used in the dict.
This is equivalent to the full version, but without condition `if k not in relations:`.

Result:

```
[{'start': '123', 'end': '456', 'type': 'a'}, {'start': '111', 'end': '122', 'type': 'b'}, {'start': '333', 'end': '222', 'type': 'c'}]
```

Comment: What are d1 and d2? There's just a list of dictionaries.

Comment: How does this treat the dictionaries with `start: x, end: y` as equivalent to `start: y, end: x` and remove the duplicates?

Comment: d1, d2, ..., d_n - are your dicts.

Comment: Can you show how this works with a list of dicts? I still don't see how it swaps `start` and `end` when comparing.

Comment: It remove duplicates, like `start: x` and make one dictionary without duplicated key/value pairs.

Comment: Can you test your code and show the results?

Comment: I think you don't really understand the question.

Comment: Look, if you have two dicts (for the list it's similar), you'll have: `{'type': 'c', 'end': '333', 'start': '222'}`

Comment: The result is supposed to be a new list of dictionaries. You're just creating one dictionary.

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry, I didn't understand, what do you need as a result.

Comment: I don't need anything, I didn't write the question.

Comment: The result is supposed to be a list of dictionaries created from the original list, but without pairs of dictionaries that have the same start/end values in either order.

Comment: Corrected. Thank you for the comments, Barmar.

Answer (score 0):

To generate a sorting key that's order-independent only for specific, named keys (as initially defined by the `sortable_keys` default parameter):

```
def order_independent_key(input_dict, sortable_keys=('start', 'end')):
    local_dict = dict(input_dict)
    sortable_vals = []
    for key in sortable_keys:
        sortable_vals.append(local_dict.pop(key))
    return tuple(sortable_vals) + tuple(sorted(local_dict.items()))
```

Thus:

```
list_of_dicts = [{'start': '123',  'end': '456', 'type':'a'},
                  {'start': '111',  'end': '122', 'type':'b'},
                  {'start': '222',  'end': '333', 'type':'c'},
                  {'start': '333',  'end': '222', 'type':'c'},
                  ]
deduplicated_dicts = {}
for item in list_of_dicts:
    deduplicated_dicts[order_independent_key(item)] = item
```

...will generate a structure like:

```
{('111', '122', ('type', 'b')): {'end': '122', 'start': '111', 'type': 'b'},
 ('123', '456', ('type', 'a')): {'end': '456', 'start': '123', 'type': 'a'},
 ('222', '333', ('type', 'c')): {'end': '333', 'start': '222', 'type': 'c'},
 ('333', '222', ('type', 'c')): {'end': '222', 'start': '333', 'type': 'c'}}
```

...for which doing a lookup by `order_independent_key(another_dict)` is an operation with performance characteristics that scale only with the number of keys in `another_dict`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would be quite efficient for looping through a list of dicts and determining which are dupes (add anything to a set that is considered "seen").  Would require looping through each dict once, but constant time lookup to see if a key exists.

```
seen = set()

for my_dict in list_of_dicts:
    if (my_dict['start'], my_dict['end']) in seen:
        # dupe
        continue
    # not dupe
    seen.add((my_dict['start'], my_dict['end']))
    seen.add((my_dict['end'], my_dict['start']))
```

Comment: Yes, define 'seen' as a set should be fine.

Comment: Is this going to create a huge seen set? double of the original list_of_dicts?

Comment: @Barmar the dict seemed a little more explicit, but agree a set is more Pythonic.  My understanding is that performance should be similar with either.

Comment: Yes. A set is essentially the same as a dict with hidden values.

Comment: @marlon depends how many dupes there are...couldn't tell ya

Comment: If I define 'seen' as an instance variable, then self.seen.add(...) would be problematic in a multiprocessing program? I have 10 processes to use this function.

Comment: @marlon there are better resources available than anything I'd write in a comment.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832554/multiprocessing-how-do-i-share-a-dict-among-multiple-processes