# multiprocessing: Can a dict be shared between two Python shell?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I come from this post [multiprocessing: How do I share a dict among multiple processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832554/multiprocessing-how-do-i-share-a-dict-among-multiple-processes)
but I want something slightly different. In that post, a dict is shared between a parent process and its child which is instantiated by the constructor `Process`. What I want is to share a dict between two Python shell.

Comment: Two seperate interactive instances of python does not share any memory in the OS. There are lots of methods for sharing data between processes, but they can't share objects in memory directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would like to do is use a [*managed dictionary*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager). The problem is that multiple processes will acquire their own instance of of a sharable dictionary if they use code such as:

```py
from multiprocessing import Manager

with Manager() as manager:
    sharable_dict = manager.dict()
    ... # etc.
```

Instead we crate a new managed dictionary of type `sharable_dict` that always returns a proxy to the same singleton managed dictionary. For this to work, all processes must connect to a common `SyncManager` server:

**File test2.py (your actual processing code)**

```py
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
from multiprocessing import current_process

address = "127.0.0.1"
port = 50000
password = "secret"

def connect_to_manager():
    BaseManager.register('sharable_dict')
    manager = BaseManager(address=(address, port), authkey=password.encode('utf-8'))
    manager.connect()
    return manager.sharable_dict()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sharable_dict = connect_to_manager()
    pid = current_process().pid
    print('My pic =', pid)
    sharable_dict[pid] = True
```

The above code gets a common, sharable dictuonary to which, for demo purposes, just adds a key that is the current process id.

**File test.py**

This file creates the managed, sharable dictionary that can be served up to any process wanting to use it and then using `subprocess.Popen` runs multiple external processes (i.e. test2.py). Finally, this code prints out the sharable dictionary to show that all 3 external processes:

```py
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager, DictProxy
from threading import Thread, Event
from test2 import address, port, password, connect_to_manager
from subprocess import Popen

the_dict = None

def get_dict():
    global the_dict

    if the_dict is None:
        the_dict = {}
    return the_dict

def server(started_event, shutdown_event):
    net_manager = BaseManager(address=(address, port), authkey=password.encode('utf-8'))
    BaseManager.register('sharable_dict', get_dict, DictProxy)
    net_manager.start()
    started_event.set() # tell main thread that we have started
    shutdown_event.wait() # wait to be told to shutdown
    net_manager.shutdown()

def main():
    started_event = Event()
    shutdown_event = Event()
    server_thread = Thread(target=server, args=(started_event, shutdown_event,))
    server_thread.start()
    # wait for manager to start:
    started_event.wait()

    processes = [Popen(['python', 'test2.py']) for _ in range(3)]
    for process in processes:
        process.communicate()

    sharable_dict = connect_to_manager()
    print('sharable dictionary =', sharable_dict)

    # tell manager we are through:
    shutdown_event.set()
    server_thread.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```None
My pic = 18736
My pic = 12476
My pic = 10584
sharable dictionary = {18736: True, 12476: True, 10584: True}
```

**Update**

This sharable dictionary, of course, only works with processes executing Python scripts. Assuming you are able to modify those scripts to connect to the server to get the sharable dictionary, then perhaps you can just place the code that needs to be executed in a "worker" function, e.g. `worker`, and create processes using `multiprocessing.Process` instances. This would result in far simpler code.

Your worker function:

**File test2.py**

```py
from multiprocessing import current_process

def worker(sharable_dict):
    pid = current_process().pid
    print('My pid =', pid)
    sharable_dict[pid] = True
```

And the code to create a sharable dictionary and create child processes that use it:

**File test.py**

```py
from multiprocessing import Manager, Process
from test2 import worker

def main():
    with Manager() as manager:
        sharable_dict = manager.dict()
        processes = [Process(target=worker, args=(sharable_dict,)) for _ in range(3)]
        for process in processes:
            process.start()
        for process in processes:
            process.join()

        print('sharable dictionary =', sharable_dict)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I will study your code.

Comment: I've added an update to the answer that show how much simpler the code would be if you can create your processes with `multiprocessing.Process` instances.